# Multiple spark scala jobs writing to same path at the same time

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have more than two Scala jobs that run at the same time and write to the same location, I would like to lock the file while one job is writing and pause the other job when lock is found. Looking for the ways to implement in spark2 using Scala.

Comment: Are the jobs interdependent i.e data written by job 1 is used by job 2 or vice versa?

Comment: no ,any one job writing to the output is enough,the other job skips if it runs little later.But sometimes they run in parallel and writing the same data twice.

Comment: I presume u mean Hive, parquet etc. Many issues found on this, so may be not a goer. That said, releases may improve things, Which version of spark2?

Comment: I am using spark2 and scala 2.11 and  output is written in parquet format.